# Bind the dynamically created controls inside ScrollViewer - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, catel

I have already created dynamic controls using .Net 4.0 using VS2010. Their, when I click a button, I used to create the different controls depend on the input from an xml file and set the dynamically created controls to a WPF window using "Content" control. Source code below,

ButtonClickMethod.cs

```
   private static void CustomControlsButton_Click(object source, RoutedEventArgs args) //button click event
    {
        CustomControls cui = new CustomControls();
        if (isFileExist)
        {
            cui.Content = cui.CreateGrid(); //Code which set the created controls to the content 
            cui.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

CreateCustomControls.cs

```
    public object CreateGrid() // responsible for control creation
    {
        int noOfRows = Attributes.Count;
        new PopulateGrid(noOfRows, Attributes);
        return grid.Get();
    }
```

CustomControls.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Client.CustomControls"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:resx="clr-namespace:YottaMark.Wpf.Label.Client.Properties"
    Title="Custom Controls" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

We are updating the framework and using Catel MVVM framework. Now I want to convert the same functionality to support `.Net 4.6.2` and MVVM.

In the updated version, I plan to bind the created controls inside the ScrollerViewer.

```
<catel:DataWindow
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Labeling.Views"
    xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
    xmlns:orc="http://www.wildgums.net.au/orc" x:Class="Labeling.Views.CustomFieldListView"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Icon="{StaticResource Icons8Printer}"
    Title="FieldsConfiguration" Height="270" Width="584" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" SizeToContent="Manual" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid>
<ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,51.424,10,16.251" Grid.Row="1">     
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</catel:DataWindow>
```

ViewModel.cs for the above WPF

```
public class CustomFieldListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IAttributesService _AttributesService;
    public bool AttributesFileExists { get; set;}
    public bool AttributesExists { get; set; }
    private static JArray Attributes;
    private static DynamicGrid grid = new DynamicGrid();

    public CustomControlListViewModel(IAttributesService AttributesService)
    {
        _AttributesService = AttributesService;
        AttributesFileExists = false;
        AttributesExists = false;
    }
}
```

The line `cui.Content = cui.CreateGrid();` in `ButtonClickMethod.cs` is response for set the created controls to Content. In the updated framework, I am using MVVM and I want to know how to set the created controls to the ScrollViewer while the above View is loading.

Please help me in doing this.

Thanks You

Comment: You should create controls with datatemplates and binding. Do you have a viewmodel that you want to display in the scrollviewer?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I have a ViewModel to display. Can you please give me a sample

Comment: I can't give you sample code illustrating what to do with an unknown viewmodel with unknown properties. What does the viewmodel represent? Does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged? Is it the DataContext of anything? What, where?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have updated the ViewModel class in my question. Please review